# Git Merging Fixing Issues

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I have a repo, with these branches:

- Master
- Changes
- Database Changes
- Order

I want to merge them into master branch. So, changes into master, then database changes .... etc etc. However, there are issues with merging because the master has been moved ahead as well while other branches were worked on.

When it says fix the files, i.e. choose how they should be, I would like them to use the branch which is getting merged down.

So for instance, if I was merging Changes into Master, I would like Git to use the Changes files. How do you specify that after a failed merge?

```
# git checkout master
# git merge Changes
# ---LOTS of ERRORs here ---
```

now do I use:

```
# git add -A
# git commit -m "Using these resolutions"
```

or something like this:

```
# git checkout Changes
# git add -A
# git commit -m "Using these resolutions"
# git checkout master
# git merge Changes
```

Comment: Note that doing this will in effect throw away large chunks of whatever changes had been made on `master` - which is likely to break the parts of those changes that aren't being thrown away. Except in some very specific situations, this is probably not the wisest route to take - although, admittedly, "hey look, there were no merge conflicts" is a lot more convenient in the short term...

Comment: sorry i'm not sure what you mean. What is this in reference too?

Comment: If you blindly ignore how `file.c` might have been modified on your master branch when you're merging, and simply replace it with `file.c` from your development branch, then you are effectively throwing away all the changes that were made in that file on your master branch. Depending on how that code depends on code in other files (and vice versa), you are going to break something by blindly throwing away the changes that were made on master...

Comment: yes i totally see that. fortunately, I work on branches for improvements then end up merging them down, the only reason the master was ahead, was because visual studio when it opens and close solution files, they get changed slighty, so I could ignore all those clashes! when it comes down to it, only about 2 changes actually properly conflict at a time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `git merge -s ours` the master into the branch you want to merge, then merge it back into master.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on what you mean with more code? thanks

Comment: I think it worked, I used that line whilst checked out in the Changes branch, then checked out back to the master and committed everything, bitbucket is saying that the master was merged into Changes

Comment: As @minitech pointed out always merge your master branch into your dev branches before you start doing any work, regularly while you are doing the work and again after you have finished to work. The merge to master will then be trivial. Lots of small merges is much easier than a monster merge.

Comment: yeah fair enough, I like that approach, so if I use `git merge -s ours`, any of exactly the same changes will be overridden by the working branch?